# Animate.css in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I would like to use `animate.css` with my wordpress theme. I placed the file in the folder `mytheme/includes/css` then used it in the file `function.php`

```
// Import Animate.css
wp_enqueue_style( 'mytheme-wp', THEME_DIR_URI . '/includes/css/animate.css' );
```

but when I use the styles of the file animate.css, they don't work.

Am I missing some steps?

[image]

Comment: Is it loading the file - check your console network tab to see if it is throwing a 404

Comment: Yes it is loading correctly the file, no 404

Comment: Are any styles on the site showing - are there any other style sheets that work? Also when  you say don't work, what exactly do you mean? don't work covers a wide range of things

Comment: The file css is loading. I add the class to a div. There is no animation. From the Chrome Inspector I select the div and in the style column, the animate.css file doesn't appear.

Comment: You can see the picture above.

Answer (score 2):

It was wrong the function.php file.
I wrote 'mytheme-wp" instead of "mytheme-animate"

The correct command is

```
// Import Animate.css

wp_enqueue_style( 'mytheme-animate', THEME_DIR_URI . '/includes/css/animate.css' );
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `animate.css` loading correctly, then just try to add classes `rubberBand animated` to any div/image from Console, if it gets animate then it works fine.